# How to revise the css transitions with a delay

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have following code

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="close">Close</a>

 <div class="box">

    <input type="text">

    <input type="text">

    <input type="text">

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.box').on('click', function () {
        $(this).addClass('animated');
    });

    $('.close').on('click', function () {
        $('.box').removeClass('animated');
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 30px;
    transition: width 0.3s ease, height 0.3s ease, border-radius 0.3s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}
input {
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box.animated {
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.box.animated > input {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/apLtw7av/)

There are two things

1) Once the box has been expanded the input elements should be visible. I have achieved this using `transition-delay` property.

2) But when the close link is clicked first the inputs opacity should be 0 and when the inputs are completely invisible then the box should go to its previous shape which is a circle.

Question: How do i achieve #2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to css

```
.box:not(.animated){
    transition-delay:0.3s;
}
.box:not(.animated) input{
    transition-delay:0s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/apLtw7av/2/

explanation:
`transition-delay` property will aply depending on having class `animated`. Clicking on close will remove `animated` class therefore aply new `transition-delay`

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks mate.. This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to show/hide input fields like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.box').on('click', function () {
        $('.box input').show();
        $(this).addClass('animated');
    });

    $('.close').on('click', function () {
        $('.box input').hide();
        $('.box').removeClass('animated');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is my anwser and an [EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/T04435/pen/bVQjVO)

```
HTML
<span class="close">X</span>
<div class="box">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>

CSS
.box {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: all 300ms ease 600ms; /*This is the only thing You need to change*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
input {
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  transition: all 300ms ease 300ms; /*input delay + input transition time 300 + 300 = 600*/
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box.animated {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.box.animated > input {
  opacity: 1;
}

.close{
  cursor:pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  font-weight:bolder;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  display:none;
}

JQuery
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.box').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('animated');
    $('.close').css({display:"block"});
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function () {
    $('.box').removeClass('animated');
    $(this).css({display:"none"});
  });

});
```

The only change you need to do is *add a delay* to the **box** so it starts after the **input**, so it goes like **input delay + input transition time**(*look at the comments in the css to see the values you need to play with*)

One more tip, when you use the same values in the transition you could use **all**

```
/*this*/
transition: all 0.3s ease;

/*is the same  as*/
transition: width 0.3s ease, height 0.3s ease, border-radius 0.3s ease;
```

#### HOPE THIS HELPS [T04435](https://github.com/T04435)